# How to fully collapse and alter content of a website without client script?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

Here is the desired "collapse" effect: [Micorsoft](http://microsoft.com) 

When I mean collapsing.. I mean **upon window resizing**, *Div's realigning, content dissapearing/appearing, ect.*

This obviously appears to be done with js, but upon being disabled and the window being refreshed several times (just to make sure), it still collapses.

My first thought was that this was accomplished via AJAX; I have researched this method without significant evidence to prove that the collapse is possible.. Though I may be wrong.


I attempted a simple window width extraction on the server end, but wasn't able to collect the correct width for dynamic content.


- I use Visual Studio 2012 on a server running IIS 6, and preferably program in vb -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "responsive web design".

Using CSS you can detect the size of the active window and adapt the format of your content accordingly.
By doing this, you ensure a consistent experience to all your users no matter the device (and its screen size) there are using.

It's not done with any server side technology, neither with Javascript but only with CSS.

Here is a good presentation if you want to know more about this: http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/

And a lot more if you google it.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. This was driving me crazy